# IDLE giving an error when MailMerge tries to work with doc/docx files

Tags: python, docx, mailmerge

I would appreciate a hand with this.

It has previously popped corrupt file errors when opening the word file, but if I change .doc to .docx and remove some hyperlinks (I understand from another post somewhere that hyperlinks, footnotes, comments all cause errors), this time IDLE pops out the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Files_*tempfiller*_\tempfiller.py", line 43, in 
document.write('TBCO.docx')
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\mailmerge.py", line 129, in write
output.writestr(zi.filename, self.zip.read(zi))
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1475, in read
with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\zipfile.py", line 1532, in open
raise BadZipFile("Truncated file header")
zipfile.BadZipFile: Truncated file header

Because this is in the mailmerge.py file I can't really understand what this is.

My code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from mailmerge import MailMerge

from datetime import date

template = "TBCO.docx" #add .docx suffix if failing
print('1')

document = MailMerge(template)
print(document.get_merge_fields())

print('2')

document.merge(
    date = '1.1.1',
    name = 'Bob',
    nhs = '2223')

print('3')

document.write('TBCO.docx')

print('4')
```

The prints were for me to see what was happening when it was giving set() repeatedly, but that's fixed. The sense I get from the error message is that it is struggling with the file type for some reason, but I can't make head nor tail of the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you just *rename* the file from `.doc` to `.docx`?  Those are profoundly different file formats, software that supports only one of them would be completely incapable of doing anything with the other.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm superficially aware of the difference, but bear in mind I had done this in an attempt to see if the problem was with the file, rather than the code. On changing it there was no difference in it corrupting whichever file format it is in. The .py is opening the file, trying to find the mergefield tags, e.g., <<example>>, that I had set up in a few places where the information was to be replaced, then closing the file in the code. The error as above occurs with the .docx, but there is a general problem with it corrupting the file even if I use .doc.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the answer, but is it because I am trying to read from and write to the file at the same time?